# Can I create a double-morphed many-to-many relationship in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two models: `Product` and `Group`, which I want to both give a many-to-many 'shown' and a 'recommended' relation with itself and the other (so both have has to be morphed in both ways).

So a 'shown' resource of either type has a set of 'recommended' resources of either type (the Groups are actually acting as a container for grouped Products).

The table should be pretty straightforward:

```
        Schema::create('recommendables', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->morphs('shown');
            $table->morphs('recommendable');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Then relations are defined in the trait 'RecommendableTrait' which is then given to both classes. As far as these relationships are concerned both classes are then handled pretty much the same later on (even to be merged into a single collection), so there is merit in trying to do it this way.

The problem is that the following relation definitions won't work, because it will look for `group_id` if I call the morphed relations on `Group`, similarly with `morphedByMany'.

```
trait RecommendableTrait {

    // RECOMMENDED GROUPS
    public function recommendedGroups()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Group::class, 'recommendable', 'recommendables')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

    // RECOMMENDED PRODUCTS
    public function recommendedProducts()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Product::class, 'recommendable', 'recommendables')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

    // SHOWN GROUPS
    public function shownGroups()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Group::class, 'shown', 'recommendables')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

    // SHOWN PRODUCTS
    public function shownProducts()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Product::class, 'shown', 'recommendables')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Now I know, I'm looking to create a bit of a weird relation tangle here. But I'm hoping defining a double-morphed many-to-many is possible in Laravel?

If not, I guess I'll have to either split it up in two single-morphed many-to-Many relationship sets for both classes. Which would be annoying because of the code that goes on top of these relations would have to be needlessly duplicated. Or I'll have to forego relations and just DB query the results directly. Thus giving up some of Eloquence's convenience, but at least allowing me to keep the code confined to a single shared trait.